# SWAPing Schmidt vectors

Tags: quantum-state, swap-test, linear-algebra, schmidt-decomposition

Can anything be said about the inner product of a bipartite entangled state with itself but with the Schmidt vectors swapped? That is, if the Schmidt decomposition of a state is given by
$$\vert \psi \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^d\sqrt{\lambda_i} \vert i_A \rangle \vert i_B \rangle,$$
then can anything be said about the inner product
$$\langle \psi \vert \psi' \rangle = \sum_{i,j=1}^d \sqrt{\lambda_i\lambda_j}\langle i_A \vert \langle i_B \vert \vert j_B \rangle \vert j_A \rangle = \sum_{i,j=1}^d \sqrt{\lambda_i\lambda_j} \langle i_A \vert j_B \rangle \cdot \langle i_B \vert j_A \rangle?$$
Note that the inner products are well-defined because in the definition of the Schmidt decomposition, the underlying Hilbert space of systems $A$ and $B$ is $\mathbb{C}^d$.
Because of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0017), I guess the answer is (Lemma 20)
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^d \lambda_i^2 \right),$$
but they get this result as a corollary of a more difficult theorem. I would be interested in seeing a direct calculation, since it seems like a very natural result that I can't seem to prove.

Comment: I feel like if anything can be said, then it might only be in the non-degenerate case because of the non-uniqueness of the Schmidt decomposition. But I would love to be proven wrong

Comment: If the Schmidt bases are the same on the two systems, doesn't that imply that the inner product is 1? That would seem to be incompatible with your guess.

Comment: I don't think this is *always* well defined. It is when you assume that they are bipartite spaces in $\mathbb{C}^d\otimes\mathbb{C}^d$ for some $d$, which needs not be the case. That aside, assuming equal dimensions, I'd guess the result will change greatly with the states. You can also get $2\lambda_1\lambda_2$ for states such as $\lambda_1|01\rangle+\lambda_2|10\rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** In general, such "inner product" is not well-defined. This can be remedied by appropriate choice of $A$ and $B$. Still, the inner product depends on the global phase and thus cannot be observed. Its absolute value - which can be observed in principle - can take any value in $[0,1]$, even for product states (in contradiction to the proposed formula).

### Well-definedness

Suppose that $A$ is a spin-$\frac12$ particle and $B$ a particle on a line and consider the state
$$
|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\left(|{\uparrow}\rangle|p_+\rangle+|{\downarrow}\rangle|p_-\rangle\right)\tag1
$$
where $|{\uparrow}\rangle$ and $|{\downarrow}\rangle$ represent the spin-up and spin-down states of $A$ and $|p_+\rangle$ and $|p_-\rangle$ represent the states of $B$ with absolute linear momentum $p$ propagating to the right and to the left, respectively. Clearly, $|{\uparrow}\rangle$ and $|p_+\rangle$ live in different Hilbert spaces, so the "inner product" $\langle{\uparrow}|p_+\rangle$ is not defined.

### Sensitivity to global phase

That said, we might choose $A$ and $B$ so that their Hilbert spaces coincide. Note that this is an *additional* assumption which is not needed for or implied by Schmidt decomposition$^1$. With the assumption, the inner product is defined, but only up to the unobservable global phase. Thus, we loose no generality by limiting our consideration to its absolute value.

### Any value in $[0,1]$ is possible

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality the absolute value of the inner product lies in $[0, 1]$. It is sufficient to consider product states to see that no further constraints on the inner product can be obtained. Indeed, fix $a\in[0,1]$ and let $|\phi\rangle=\sqrt{a}|0\rangle+\sqrt{1-a}|1\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle=|0\rangle|\phi\rangle$. Then
$$
\langle\psi|\psi'\rangle=\langle 0|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|0\rangle=a\tag2.
$$
Thus, we can make the inner product equal to any desired number $a\in[0,1]$. In particular, the proposed formula predicts $\langle\psi|\psi'\rangle=1$ for all product states so it can't be correct.

---

<sup>$^1$ In particular, Schmidt decomposition is well-defined when $A$ and $B$ have Hilbert spaces of different dimension. In this case, $d$ is the smaller one.</sup>